# How to create more vertical space between the NavigationRail Icons while the width of the rail is minimum?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create more vertical space between the icons in the NavigationRail. While the width of the rail stays at his minimum of 56px. So the setting of labelType has to be `labelType.none` .

I have tried to wrap the Icon with `Padding()`, `Container()`, `SizedBox()`. Nothing works.

Any solution for this problem?

Thx

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          NavigationRail(
            onDestinationSelected: (newIndex) {
              setState(() {
                selectedIndex = newIndex;
              });
            },
            elevation: 3,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
            groupAlignment: 0,
            selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
                label: Text('Home'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.event_available),
                label: Text('Events'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.local_parking_outlined),
                label: Text('Parking'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood_outlined),
                label: Text('Food'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.medical_services_outlined),
                label: Text('S.O.S.'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[list[selectedIndex],],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Is there a good way to share the code. Sorry very new here.

Comment: You can edit the question you've posted and can add the code. I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask